# SwiftUI - Can I define an empty initializer for a generic view?

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui

I have a generic view with an optional `@ViewBuilder`.
I want to have two initializers, one is responsible for setting the `@ViewBuilder` and another which should serve as an empty default.

```
struct OptionalViewBuilder<Content: View>: View {
    
    let content: (() -> Content)?
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    init() {
        self.content = nil
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Headline")
            Divider()
            content?()
        }
    }
}
```

If I initialize the view with the ViewBuilder parameter, it works of course. However, when I use the empty initializer, I get the error message:

> Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        OptionalViewBuilder {
            Text("Text1")
            Text("Text2")
        }
        OptionalViewBuilder() // <-- Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred
    }
}
```

I know that Swift needs explicit types at runtime, but is there a way to make the default initializer work anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `OptionalViewBuilder` is generic with respect to its `Content` type, you'd need to define that type as *something* in your default case. This could be `EmptyView`, if you don't want to render anything.

To do that, you'd need an `init` which is constrained to `Content == EmptyView`, and the `content` property need not be optional:

```
struct OptionalViewBuilder<Content: View>: View {
    
    let content: () -> Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    init() where Content == EmptyView {
        self.init(content: { EmptyView() })
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Headline")
            Divider()
            content()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can make the compile error go away by adding an empty closure, like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        OptionalViewBuilder {
            Text("Text1")
            Text("Text2")
        }
        OptionalViewBuilder() {} // I added an empty closure
    }
}
```

Does this get you what you need?

Answer (score -1):

You also can pass EmptyView() as default parameter

```
struct OptionalViewBuilder<Content: View>: View {
    
   let content: () -> Content?

   init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content? = { EmptyView() }) {
        self.content = content
    }
}
```